# Why don't the error limits in my plots show in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was going through [this example of matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/statistics/errorbar_limits.html) and their plot has upper and lower limits **with an additional perpendicular line to show when they end**:

[image]

but when I do it in my python 3.7 vscode with the **exact same code** I get this:

[image]

Why? **I want the extra prependicular lines on the x and y limits to always show**. How do I do this?

Code from tutorial:

```
"""
Demo of the errorbar function, including upper and lower limits
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example data
x = np.arange(0.5, 5.5, 0.5)
y = np.exp(-x)
xerr = 0.1
yerr = 0.2
ls = 'dotted'

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# standard error bars
plt.errorbar(x, y, xerr=xerr, yerr=yerr, ls=ls, color='blue')

# including upper limits
uplims = np.zeros(x.shape)
uplims[[1, 5, 9]] = True
plt.errorbar(x, y + 0.5, xerr=xerr, yerr=yerr, uplims=uplims, ls=ls,
             color='green')

# including lower limits
lolims = np.zeros(x.shape)
lolims[[2, 4, 8]] = True
plt.errorbar(x, y + 1.0, xerr=xerr, yerr=yerr, lolims=lolims, ls=ls,
             color='red')

# including upper and lower limits
plt.errorbar(x, y + 1.5, marker='o', ms=8, xerr=xerr, yerr=yerr,
             lolims=lolims, uplims=uplims, ls=ls, color='magenta')

# including xlower and xupper limits
xerr = 0.2
yerr = np.zeros(x.shape) + 0.2
yerr[[3, 6]] = 0.3
xlolims = lolims
xuplims = uplims
lolims = np.zeros(x.shape)
uplims = np.zeros(x.shape)
lolims[[6]] = True
uplims[[3]] = True
plt.errorbar(x, y + 2.1, marker='o', ms=8, xerr=xerr, yerr=yerr,
             xlolims=xlolims, xuplims=xuplims, uplims=uplims, lolims=lolims,
             ls='none', mec='blue', capsize=0, color='cyan')

ax.set_xlim((0, 5.5))
ax.set_title('Errorbar upper and lower limits')
plt.show()
```

---

Edit:

now it only works if I manually specify the capsize instead of a global...why?

```
            fig, (loss_ax1, acc_ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)

            loss_ax1.plot(episodes_train_x, train_loss_y, label='Train Loss', linestyle='-', marker='o', color='r', linewidth=1)
            loss_ax1.errorbar(episodes_eval_x, eval_loss_y, yerr=eval_loss_std, label=f'{eval_label} Loss', linestyle='-', marker='o', color='m', linewidth=1, capsize=3)
            loss_ax1.legend()
            loss_ax1.set_title('Meta-Learnig & Evaluation Curves')
            loss_ax1.set_ylabel('Meta-Loss')
            loss_ax1.grid(grid)

            acc_ax2.plot(episodes_train_x, train_acc_y, label='Accuracy', linestyle='-', marker='o', color='b', linewidth=1)
            acc_ax2.errorbar(episodes_eval_x, eval_acc_y, yerr=eval_acc_std, label=f'{eval_label} Accuracy', linestyle='-', marker='o', color='c', linewidth=1, capsize=3)
            acc_ax2.legend()
            acc_ax2.set_xlabel('Episodes (Outer Epochs)')
            acc_ax2.set_ylabel('Meta-Accuracy')
            acc_ax2.grid(grid)

            plt.tight_layout()

            #plt.show() if show else None
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `capsize` parameter to set the length of the caps, e.g.

```
plt.errorbar(x, y, xerr=xerr, yerr=yerr, ls=ls, color='blue', capsize=3)
```

Or to set the option once for all plots:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams["errorbar.capsize"] = 3
```

Sample code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams["errorbar.capsize"] = 3

# example data
x = np.arange(0.5, 5.5, 0.5)
y = np.exp(-x)
xerr = 0.1
yerr = 0.2
ls = 'dotted'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(6, 6))

# standard error bars
ax[0].errorbar(x, y, xerr=xerr, yerr=yerr, ls=ls, color='blue')

# including upper limits
uplims = np.zeros(x.shape)
uplims[[1, 5, 9]] = True
ax[1].errorbar(x, y + 0.5, xerr=xerr, yerr=yerr, uplims=uplims, ls=ls,
             color='green')
```

[image]

Comment: Second one does not work. I am creating specific figs & axis. Is that why the second doesn't work? (I prefer that one than specifying it manually for all the plots and axis etc)

Comment: How does it "not work"? What's your code? Added sample code and output with specific axes.

Comment: fig, (loss_ax1, acc_ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)

Comment: Not works means that the cap things still dont wappear, EXCEPT when I put them in the errorbars command. I am creating figures seperately rather than using plt. Does that help?

Comment: I pasted the main thing that I think we care about but will edit it too

Comment: I can't repro (as you see, added a code snippet that demonstrates use of specific axes).